# React Redux app - complex init action composition executes final promise before the others are done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, middleware, redux, thunk

I'm working on an app which has to manage a large amount of data.
In the init process several api calls must be done while the user sees a loading bar.

Here is my init action:

```
export function init(key) {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    // start init
    dispatch(initStart());

    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(initProcess(10));
    }, 0)


    return Promise.all([

      // load users
      dispatch(loadUsers(key)).then(() => {
        dispatch(initProcess(30));
      }),

      // load other stuff
      // ...

      // load articles
      dispatch(loadArticles(key)).then(() => {
        dispatch(initProcess(60));
      }),

    // should be executed after all actions/reducers are done
    ]).then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(initFinish());
      }, 700);
    });
  }
}
```

So far it works perfectly, but there will be 20k to 50k articles. The backend has to perform some joins to get the data together, so I'm sure I'll get a server timeout if I try to get them in one piece.

The idea is to fetch the total number first and then get the articles in 1k pieces in a loop. But it wont work the way I need it. I'm getting `initFinish` dispatched after the articles are counted but not after they are fetched.

Here is the `loadArticles` action:

```
export function loadArticles(key) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    // check local db first

    // get total number
    return dispatch(countArticles(key))
    .then(result => {
      Promise.all([
        // No idea how to put the loop in here :(
        dispatch(fetchArticles(key, 1000)),
      ])
    });
 }
```

}

I have no loop yet but thats not the point. The logic remains the same. I return the `dispatch(countArticles(key))` before `fetchArticles` is done.

Has anyone a hint? That would be awesome.

---

**EDIT**

`coutArticles` and `fetchArticles`

```
function countArticles(key) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [ COUNT_ARTICLES_REQUEST, COUNT_ARTICLES_SUCCESS, COUNT_ARTICLES_FAILURE ],
      endpoint: `articles`,
      schema: Schemas.ARTICLE_COUNTER
    }
  }
}
function fetchArticles(key, take, skip) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [ FETCH_ARTICLES_REQUEST, FETCH_ARTICLES_SUCCESS, FETCH_ARTICLES_FAILURE ],
      endpoint: `articles/${take}/${skip}`,
      schema: Schemas.ARTICLE_ARRAY
    }
  }
}
```

The middleware is the same es [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js)

---

**2. EDIT**

if i change

```
// get total number
return dispatch(countArticles(key))
.then(result => {
  Promise.all([
    // No idea how to put the loop in here :(
    dispatch(fetchArticles(key, 1000)),
  ])
});
```

to

```
// get total number
dispatch(countArticles(key))
.then(result => {
  return Promise.all([
    // No idea how to put the loop in here :(
    dispatch(fetchArticles(key, 1000)),
  ])
});
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on `dispatch(loadArticles(key))`.

---

**3. EDIT**

Some days later I'm still fighting ^^

Here is the simplified init function, which should (only) get the count result and then fetch the articles:

But for now im failing already here:

```
export function init(key) {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    countArticles(key).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });

  }
}
```

Output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: countArticles(...).then is not a function
```

Comment: Try moving the `return` to the `dispatch` call inside `Promise.all`

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but `Promise.all` accepts an array. `return` as a array value would be a syntax error ?!

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I didn't think it all the way through :P

Comment: Maybe try `return Promise.all()` instead?

Comment: already tried, doesn't work either.

Comment: And you removed the `return` from the top-level `dispatch`?

Comment: nope, ill try it in one hour. Im at currently work. Do you mean the `return (dispatch, getState)` inside the `loadArticles` or the one from the `init`?

Comment: I mean change `return dispatch(countArticles(key))` to just `dispatch(countArticles(key))` and `Promise.all()` to `return Promise.all()`.

Comment: yes, tried so. does not work :( - I'll tell you later how the exact error is. It says something like "then of undefined". I think its because there must be this specific return for the promise

Comment: Can you post the `countArticles` function? If that isn't returning a `Promise` then you'd probably get that error.

Comment: `countArticles` and `fetchArticles` are going through a middleware. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with chaining dispatch as well; it should return a `Promise` but I could not get it to work.

So I would change the logic this way

```
countArticles(key).then(result => {
    dispatch( {
        type:  RECEIVED_NUM_ARTICLES,
        value: result
    })
    Promise.all([...Array(Math.floor(result/1000))].map(_ => 
         fetchArticles(key,1000).then(res => dispatch( {
            type:  RECEIVED_1000_ARTICLES,
            value: res
         })
    )).then( _ => dispatch({
            type:  RECEIVED_EVERYTHING
            value: 'whatever'
         })
    )
)
```

(I did not test this code)

But basically: `fetch` then `dispatch` the result, then chain another fetch/dispatch sequence, etc...

The loop needs rework to fetch the modulo

The advantage with this approach is that you can update the UI with the number of articles when you have them, then provide updates on every 1000 articles fetched and finally notify when done

Comment: I know, you've said its not tested, but should it be something like `return dispatch(countArticles(key)).then ... ` because I'm getting an error `countArticles(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Oh, I think you focused on the loop, but that is not my main problem. In fact it's currently not a problem at all. I'm having trouble with the order of the dispatched actions.

Comment: Isn't `countArticles` returning a `Promise` following an Ajax call ?

Comment: Anyway, the las comment stands: fetch -> dispatch -> fetch -> dispatch; do not chain dispatches, chain fetches

Comment: You should not try to return the `countArticles` dispatch. It causes a race condition with `fetchArticles()`. You will need to wrap it in the `dispatch` function, however, because the middleware returns a `Promise`. Use the code above and just modify it to read `dispatch(countArticles(key)).then(...)` and it should work.

Comment: thank you both. I'll try. I bet it is not that difficult, but its new for me ;)

Comment: hey guys, i've let it sink for some days, but now I'm not really further. Would you please check the 3rd edit?